# MockMvc is null when testing the Web Layer

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, mocking

I have this MvcTest in my application:

```
@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest
public class BarsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;



    @Test
    public void testBars() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/bars")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(1)));
    }
}
```

but when I run the test mockMvc is null when running the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `@WebMvcTest` and `@SpringBootTest` together.

If you want to test both web layer and other layers Use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and `@SpringBootTest`  together:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BarsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;



    @Test
    public void testBars() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/bars")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(1)));
    }
}
```

Or if you only want to test web layer you can use just `@WebMvcTest`: note the this does not load full spring application context(It only loads web layer)

```
@WebMvcTest
public class BarsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;



    @Test
    public void testBars() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/bars")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: with the second approach I still got null